# Rails select helper, prompt: 'Select' is hidden after other option is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a select tag with `prompt: 'Select'` option. It generates this option

```
 <option value="" style="display: none;">Select</option>
```

When any other option is chosen, this is automatically hidden. Why the style is hidden? I would want to get back to the original `Select` state after selecting any other options. What am i doing wrong? If the style is not hidden, my problem is solved, how to get over it?

In view file

```
  <%= select_tag "policy", options_for_select(Policy.all.collect{|policy| [policy.name, policy.id, { "data-price" => policy.price}] }), prompt: "Select",  class: 'policy pull-right' %>
```

Comment: Can you show your associated view code for this?

Comment: Do you use any javascript select plugin?

Comment: There is jquery.ui, jquery.switchbutton libraries used. There is no work around?